# Run option periodically disables when trying to debug extension

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to debug my share extension on a device, but periodically the Product > Run options is disabled. I used to be able to deactivate the scheme and reactivate it to get the option working again, but it seems stuck now. Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Executable in the Debug section of the scheme to None then back to Ask on Launch fixes it.